# Does SignalR 1.2.2 support to create a server in Winform?

Tags: winforms, signalr

I need to create SignalR in a .Net Winform application using the framework 4.0.

I know SignalR 1.2.2 supports .Net 4.0.

But, can I use it to create a web server in the Winform project?

If yes, is there a sample of it?
Thanks a lot!
Jun

Comment: You mean a self hosted SignalR service on winforms application? Yes. There's a tutorial [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host)

Comment: 1.2.2? Do you really need that old version as well as .NET 4? Microsoft now only supports .NET 4.5.2 and above.

Comment: Yes, but the tutorial is for .NET 4.5.  I need a version for .NET 4.0. Thanks!